# How to identify TeXlive or MikTex on TeXStudio

Tags: miktex, texlive, texstudio

I'd like to know how to identify that TeXStudio runs TeXlive or MikTex.

Comment: Generally, no. I'd say it is the other way around due to the default font in miktex. The distribution is listed on the first line of the log file.

Comment: you should expect identical pdfs other than internal identifying metadata with miktex or texlive. assuming you have same packages and fonts installed with both systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way. After each compile, in the message window under tab log->log file, if the first line is displayed as:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live ...)
```

Then TeXStudio runs TeXlive.